# Finding absolute min and min of function on a region D

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

The Question: Find the absolute maximum value of the function $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2-12x+16y$ on the region $D=\{(x,y)|x^2+y^2 \le25 \}$.

I was able to find the critical points of the original function: $(6, -8)$.

I'm just confused on how to find the critical points of the circular region. I've tried setting $y^2=25-x^2$ and plugging that into the original function, but I was still struggling to find the critical points.

Comment: to find the critical points of the circular region:

find $\max_{y}(-12\sqrt{25-y^2}+16y+25)$ by differentiation

Comment: @George Dewhirst Thank you, it worked!